# NoneType in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Voting(id unique, name text ,Zone text ,is_voted integer)""")
```

I have a iD,whose row I want to fetch and I have that in my database.

```
id=int(iD)
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Voting WHERE id={}".format(id))
Iden=c.fetchone()
print(Iden)
identification,user_name,dep_Money,Is=Iden
```

I tried all solutions and it still show this

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Insertion into DB

```
 c.execute("INSERT INTO Voting VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(self.id_label.text(),self.name_label.text(),self.zone_label.text(),0))
```

I checked the database and iD for that row is there.I dont know its showing Nonetype.Please help me

Comment: Your `fetchone` query is returning None. I think you need to use quote for `id`. Try `"SELECT * FROM Voting WHERE id='{}'".format(id))`

Comment: Show the code that writes the row to the database.

Comment: I have added it.Please say a solution.

Comment: I tried quoting it.It shows bad builtin operation

Comment: It seems the problem is in the table I created.I gave unique id.When I changed to integer its working.How do keep a unique id here?

Answer (score 0):

The code writes the ID as a string, but then searches for a number.

You should insert the value with the correct type:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Voting VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(int(self.id_label.text()), ...
                                                ^^^^
```